# Problems with logic in jQuery .click() method

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with understanding logic in this piece of code:

```
$(".not-clicked").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    $(this).removeClass("not-clicked");    
    console.log("123");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6yvp1dL/1/

What I was going to do is to change class of ".not-clicked" div to ".clicked" after it's clicked. But after it changes, new clicks on ".clicked" div keep logging '123' just like if it was still ".not-clicked". Why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the event delegation happens *only once* when the code written is first executed. It is not a rule which is matched for the future, it is simply assigned once and that is all it considers. In your demo you have 4 divs which are all classes 'not-clicked', however, as far as the collection of elements is concerned it would have been just the same as using 'div' as your selector.

If you wish the delegate the events to the future, so that only elements matching the selector given in the future have the event handled, then you should use jQuery's `on`. `on` will attach an event handler to a parent object, and any time an event is processed it will look for a child element matching the selector and then issue the event callback using that element as the scope (`this`).

```
$('body').on('click','.not-clicked',function(){
 $(this).addClass("clicked");
 $(this).removeClass("not-clicked");    
 console.log("123");
});
```

Comment: Thank you and the other guys for the full and complete replies : )

Answer (score 0):

The `click` function only finds and binds events to elements when the function is first called.  Instead, you need to use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.not-clicked', function(){
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      $(this).removeClass('not-clicked');
      console.log('123');
 });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/s6yvp1dL/3/